# Pay online with a card and then block it - any threats?

Tags: credit-card, payment

Sometimes I order stuff from less-known online stores that ask me to pay directly by providing a card number.
Either they don't support PayPal or similar services or they might charge a fee for using them, so that's what I do:

- I have a card with about $200 on it. This card is blocked by default.
- When I need to use it, I unblock it in an app, provide the PAN/CVV/whatever to the untrusted website, authorize the transaction and immediately block the card again.

How safe is this? What could a threat actor do with PAN/CVV considering that the card is blocked 99.99% of the time?

Comment: Normally we're not big on production recommendations, but just use privacy.com.  It's better in all respects

Comment: Little remark: privacy.com is exclusive for US residents...

Comment: If your bank supports it, use Virtual Card Numbers. My bank supports it, and I use it sometimes. It creates a card that is only good for one transaction, and gets revoked immediately.

Comment: Yes @ThoriumBR my bank has this offer... but it requires a Premium account with monthly fee (even if I'm not using the feature!), so I'm not using their one-time cards. Thanks for the info about privacy.com being for US only; that basically precludes me from using it at all! :)

Comment: What are you worried about? If there's a fraudulent charge, call your bank, get your money back, and get a new card. It's not convenient, but it's not much trouble either